# I am not getting the value of 'steps' from this React Native code

Tags: react-native

{this.state.isEnded ? 'Congrats! You have completed in $ {this.state.steps} steps.': 'You have tried $ {this.state.steps} time(s).'}

What is wrong?
React-native android development

Comment: Please share the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{this.state.isEnded ? <Text>Congrats! You have completed in {this.state.steps} steps.</Text>:<Text>You have tried {this.state.steps} time(s).</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

{this.state.isEnded ? <`>Congrats! You have completed in ${this.state.steps} steps.<`>: <`>You have tried ${this.state.steps} time(s).<`>}

replace <> with blank